# AWS EBS - How to pull environment name into .ebextensions script

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a grails app that I deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk through Jenkins. I want to add a splunk forwarder to my project so I can keep track of my logs outside of AWS and set up easy notifications.

The problem is, I have multiple environments of the app running (dev, pre-prod, prod, etc), which is fine because you can just change the environment name for the forwarded and be able to easily sort through that in Splunk.

However, the same .ebextensions file has to be used between all the environments, no I need a way to set the environment name to whatever AWS has the name as. Is there a way I can easily do this that I'm overlooking?

Start of the script:

```
container_commands:
    01install-splunk:
        command: /usr/local/bin/install-splunk.sh
    02set-splunk-outputs:
        command: /usr/local/bin/set_splunk_outputs.sh
        env:
            SPLUNK_SERVER_HOST: "splunk.host"
    03add-inputs-to-splunk:
        command: /usr/local/bin/add-inputs-to-splunk.sh
        env:
            ENVIRONMENT_NAME: "Development"
        cwd: /root
        ignoreErrors: false
```

That `ENVIRONMENT_NAME` variable I'm setting that's passed to the 3rd script is what I want to be able to change based on what environment is being deployed. Can I set this in Jenkins or pull it through AWS somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below steps:

1. Configure your AWS Elasticbeanstalk environment with the environment variable
   ENVIRONMENT_NAME = 'Development' or 'QA' or 'Prod'

please refer [aws-official-docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-pass-variables/) for same.

2. Then update config as below:

```sh
container_commands:
    01install-splunk:
        command: /usr/local/bin/install-splunk.sh
    02set-splunk-outputs:
        command: /usr/local/bin/set_splunk_outputs.sh
        env:
            SPLUNK_SERVER_HOST: "splunk.host"
    03add-inputs-to-splunk:
        command: /usr/local/bin/add-inputs-to-splunk.sh
        env:
            ENVIRONMENT_NAME: "$ENVIRONMENT_NAME"
        cwd: /root
        ignoreErrors: false
```

Hope this should work for you.